# Fluent NHibernate: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to develop a simple application in ASP.NET MVC WEB API in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Every thing seems to be correct, but I receive this error:

> 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified'

Source Error:

```
Line 104:        {
Line 105:            // Build the NHibernate ISessionFactory object
Line 106:            var sessionFactory = FluentNHibernate
Line 107:                .Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
Line 108:                .Database(
```

Source File: c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectConfigurator.cs    Line: 106

Stack Trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341687
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5353471
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +923
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +646
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +112
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare() +14
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) +84
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) +78
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) +700
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +104
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +41

[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

]
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +61
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectConfigurator.ConfigureNHibernate(IKernel container) in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectConfigurator.cs:106
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectConfigurator.AddBindings(IKernel container) in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectConfigurator.cs:48
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectConfigurator.Configure(IKernel container) in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectConfigurator.cs:35
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:59
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel() in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:48
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\Bootstrapper.cs:50
   MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in c:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\Mvc4ServicesBook-master\src\MVC4ServicesBook.Web.Api\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:27

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +155
   WebActivator.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +78
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +342
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +22

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +547
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9955652
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730382/1661691).

In my case, this is wrong because of the server

`<!--<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Trusted_Connection=True;database=Milano_Dev;server=(local);Integrated Security=True" />-->`

this was correct

`<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Trusted_Connection=True;database=Milano_Dev;server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True" />`

Basically this depends on your data connection. My code only based on my situation. Hopefully this is helpful to those who still have the answer.